# Azure Storage Static Website security issues

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am working in an Azure Storage Static Website. This website is publicly available and is intended to perform operations against Azure Storage (manage multimedia - crud actions). I am afraid that since it is a client-side app, anybody can use the code to perform unintended operations against the storage account. Any thoughts how can i protect the app against this? Also i am looking for a solution to avoid hardcoded keys/SAS tokens to have permission for the operations against the storage account. I was thinking about using the managed service identity. Anyone had experience with it, since it is in preview mode?

Comment: I found some articles talking about RASP solution, but i am not sure if definitely this will work, since i never worked with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely not put keys or SAS tokens client-side. As you say, anybody can obtain this and get access to the storage account. One solution is to use an HTTP-triggered serverless function to generate a SAS token as needed. Then you can issue a time-limited SAS to only the resources you want to be publicly accessible. The below tutorial shows how to do this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/functions/tutorial-static-website-serverless-api-with-database

Comment: Thanks @Michael. Definitely it is the way we are going, so we are using a Function App with Function Proxy to provide the different operations we need. We will always end up exposing something. In this case, we are exposing the URL to the function app endpoint. We will use the optimization of the angular compiler to minify and turn the code "unreadable" in order to make it harder any kind of hack attempt.

Answer (score 2):

The static website endpoint is strictly read only. So the client will not be able to change the content of the website.

Currently static website is anonymous access. "add oauth" will be added soon. For read access, once the site is enabled, it'll be available to all public.

Currently we don't have oauth support. Anybody can read the content of the website as long as they have the uri

Comment: Well, the problem is not about changing the content of the website. The problem was to be able to read content (SAS tokens) that would give permissions to any kind of hack attempt against our Azure services. We have no tokens and keys now, but we have an URL for an endpoint of a Azure Function App that will perform the operations... It is impossible to do not expose something since it is client-side app, i would say.